# Mongoose: Apply function on schema field in query condition

Tags: node.js, mongoose

In MySQL it is possible to apply native function on a filed in where clause. For example.

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE DATE(the_date) < '2012-11-19';
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE a+b < 20;
```

Now, is it possible to use a function on condition field of mongoose query? Let's say I'm querying something like this:

```
tSchema.find({a+b: {$lt: 20}}, callback);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't create computed columns with `find`, so you'd have to use [`aggregate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-aggregate) for this which is more flexible, but also slower.

Like this:

```
tSchema.aggregate([

    // Include the a, b, and a+b fields from each doc
    { $project: {
        a: 1,
        b: 1,
        sum: {$add: ['$a', '$b']}}},

    // Filter the docs to just those where sum < 20
    { $match: {sum: {$lt: 20}}}

], function(err, result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

For completeness, I should note that you can do this with `find` and a `$where` filter, but the performance of that is terrible, so it isn't recommended.  Like so:

```
tSchema.find({$where: 'this.a + this.b < 20'}, function(err, result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: and what if I don't want to get a column from two existing ones, but want to apply simple function like `a+1` or call a JS function on a field?

Comment: @ArVan You can use numbers in an `$add` operator too: `aplus1: {$add: ['$a', 1]}`

Comment: can I use the sum field in another computed field? like this:
`x: {$add: ['$sum', 1]`

Comment: @ArVan Not in the same `$project`, but you can in a subsequent one in the same pipeline.

Comment: Thanks @JohnnyHK. And what about some complicated functions? let's say I need to get distance for each record from a pre-defined location? (the collection has a location field).

Comment: @ArVan All the possible expression operators are listed in the [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/#aggregation-expression-operators).  I don't see any geo-location operators.

Comment: yes I have noticed that. I was wondering whether I can use ordinary javascript function in `$project`.